# wxpython browse file (code needed)

Tags: python, wxpython

Can anybody post up an easy code snippet for wxpython that allows the user to browse for a *.html file and have the python program take that .html file the user browsed to, and move it to a folder on my Desktop called "user-site"? I really need help making this browse feature.. any help is much appreciated. Thx in advance! :)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't already have it, download the excellent [wxPython demo](http://www.wxpython.org/download.php). In the Common Dialogs section of the demo there is a FileDialog example that shows you how to do the first part. In the block starting with `if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:` you'll need something like `shutil.move(path, "C:\path\to\your\Desktop\user-site")`. (See [shutil.move()](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html#shutil.move))